# MySQL optimize query where primary key also in almost the same selection

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I need to select all messages (incoming and outgoing) of user.id=1 from chats (both of type 'normal' and 'service') that has 'morning' event

This display them (selection 1 on image attached)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `message`
JOIN chat
ON message.chat_id = chat.id
JOIN event
ON chat.event_id = event.id
JOIN chat_type
ON chat.chat_type_id = chat_type.id
WHERE (sender = 1 or recipient = 1)
AND event.name = 'morning'
```

But i have to exclude 'service' messages where i am a sender.
This works well but I don't like it (selection 2 on image)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `message`
JOIN chat
ON message.chat_id = chat.id
JOIN event
ON chat.event_id = event.id
JOIN chat_type
ON chat.chat_type_id = chat_type.id
WHERE (sender = 1 or recipient = 1)
AND event.name = 'morning'
AND message.id NOT IN (
    SELECT message.id 
    FROM `message`
    JOIN chat
    ON message.chat_id = chat.id
    JOIN event
    ON chat.event_id = event.id
    JOIN chat_type
    ON chat.chat_type_id = chat_type.id
    WHERE (sender = 1 or recipient = 1)
    AND sender = 1 
AND chat_type.name = 'service'
)
```

Schema and select results:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you like your solution? How long does it take to run? How many records are there? If you would like us to optimise your query, then pls share all indexes you have on the affected table and the result of the explain of your query.

Comment: We don't have much fields yet ;) Only primary and foreign key fields were indexed. I think that IF-ELSE in where clause could be used instead of sub query, but interesting - what works faster on millions rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explain why you don't like the solution you have.

From your description and the example, the sub-select is redundant and innefficient:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `message`
JOIN chat
  ON message.chat_id = chat.id
JOIN event
  ON chat.event_id = event.id
JOIN chat_type
  ON chat.chat_type_id = chat_type.id
WHERE (message.sender = 1 or message.recipient = 1)
AND event.name = 'morning'
AND NOT (
   message.sender = 1  /* or whatever your id is */ 
   AND chat_type.name = 'service'
);
```

(you should also explicitly call out the attributes you are selecting)

Comment: Thanks, you'll not believe, but I forgot about "NOT" ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `union` instead of the `or` condition in the `where` criteria an then you can do the filtering without a subquery:

```
    (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  `message`
            JOIN  chat  ON message.chat_id = chat.id
            JOIN  event  ON chat.event_id = event.id
            JOIN  chat_type  ON chat.chat_type_id = chat_type.id
            WHERE  sender = 1
              AND  event.name = 'morning'
              AND  chat_type.name <> 'service'
    )
    UNION  
    (
        SELECT  *
            FROM  `message`
            JOIN  chat  ON message.chat_id = chat.id
            JOIN  event  ON chat.event_id = event.id
            JOIN  chat_type  ON chat.chat_type_id = chat_type.id
            WHERE  recipient = 1
              AND  event.name = 'morning'
    )
```

MySQL cannot use an index to satisfy an `or` operation at the moment, so using a `union` is a common optimisation technique. I would also consider excluding `chat_type` table from the query and filter on `chat_type_id<>2` instead. Along the same lines you can get rid of the `event` table as well. Even if you decide to keep this tables, you should do the filtering on the numeric id fields, and not on the textual values.

Alternatively, you can tweak your `or` condition to do the filtering without a subquery:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  `message`
    JOIN  chat  ON message.chat_id = chat.id
    JOIN  event  ON chat.event_id = event.id
    JOIN  chat_type  ON chat.chat_type_id = chat_type.id
    WHERE  ((sender = 1
                      AND  chat_type.name <> 'service')
              or  recipient = 1
           )
      AND  event.name = 'morning'
```